# How is $y'=x^2+1$ a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From James Stewart Essential Calculus Early Transcendentals Textbook,

> A differential equation is an equation that contains an unknown function and one or more of its derivatives.

But the equation
$y'=x^2+1$
doesn't contain the unknown function $y$, it only contains $y'$ and $x$. And yet my textbook says its a DE of order 1.

Even Wikipedia says a DE "relates one or more functions and their derivatives", but $y'=x^2+1$ doesn't contain the function $y$ so how is it a DE ?

Comment: Yes. This is actually a separable differential equation.

Comment: You can define a differential equation as an equation that represents the relation between independent variables, dependent variable and derivative of the dependent variable with respect to the independent variables.

Comment: @SeanRoberson If you solve it, you get $y=\frac{x^3}{3}+x+c$. So the DE $y'=x^2+1$ doesn't contain the unknown function $y$, it only contains $y'$ and $x$. So how is it a differential equation according to the definition?

Comment: @SmritiSivakumar Your definition makes the most sense to me. But Wikipedia also defines DE as "equation that relates one or more functions and their derivatives." and I still think according to that definition or the one given in James Stewart textbook $y'=x^2+1$ would not be a DE because it doesn't contain the unknown function $y$.

Comment: You can think of it as a degenerate DE, the same way how $0$ is a complex function of several variables.

Comment: $y' = x^2 + 1 + 0y$ there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the following definition may clear your doubts in all matter. This is taken from "[An Introduction to Differential Equations and Their Applications](https://www.amazon.in/Introduction-Differential-Equations-Applications-Mathematics/dp/048644595X)" by Stanley J Farlow.

> - A **differential equation** is an equation that relates the *derivatives of an unknown function*, the *function itself*, the *variables by which the function is defined*, and *constants*.
> - If the unknown function depends on a single real variable, the differential equation is called an **ordinary differential equation**.
> - A **partial differential equation** is one that contains partial derivatives with respect to more than one independent variable.

An $n^\text{th}$-order ordinary differential equation is an equation that has the
general form $$F\left(x, y, y',\cdots,y^{(n)}\right) = 0\tag1$$where the unknown quantity $y = y(x)$ is called the dependent variable, the real variable, $x$, is called the independent variable, the primes $"~'~"$ denote differentiation with respect to $x$, that is, $y' = \frac{∂y}{∂x},~~ y'' = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and so on.

Now lets come to your equation, which can be written as $~y'=x^2+1\implies y'-x^2-1=0~.$ 
So here it contains *derivatives of an unknown function* $~y~$, which is $y'$, the variable $~x,~$ and the constant $1~.$ Hence by the definition given above it is a differential equation and in particular it is an ordinary differential equation.

Answer (score 5):

That definition is not a very good one, for the reason you're pointing out here. To be precise, an ordinary differential equation of positive integer order $n$ is one which can be written in the form

$$ F\left(x, y, y',\dots,y^{(n)}\right) = 0 $$

where $y$ is an unknown function of the single variable $x$, and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{(n)}} \not\equiv 0$. The upshot of that condition is that the degree will be equal to the highest order of derivative present in the equation, barring cancellations.

---

For your example given,

$$ F\left(x,y, y'\right) = y' - x^2 - 1 $$

with $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} = 1 \neq 0$, so it is a first order ordinary differential equation. This should align with your instinct upon inspection, even if it technically disagrees with Stewart's definition.